# Float table with subfloat extend to multiple pages LyX

Tags: tables, lyx, longtable

I have a float (table) which contains several subfloats. The last of these subfloats does not fit on the page and is cut off. I would like it to extend to the next page. I know of `longtable` but that does not work with floats in LyX.  What is the right solution here?

Comment: longtable doesn't float at all it's not a lyx restriction. If you have that many floats can not they be separate floats rather than subfloats, a float is like a minipage and never breaks over a page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: well this is a table with several panels that relate to each other and so i wanted to keep them together. the reason i use floats is because the tables are actually TeX code that i simply paste into an ERT box in lyx

Comment: if you have a way to make this work in lyx without floats that works too

Comment: sorry never used lyx

Comment: As David Carlisle said, "A longtable cannot be put into a table float because floats can only be on one page." [see LyX wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables#longtab-cap). Maybe you could add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is to use `\ContinuedFloat`.  This corrects the numbering of tables and allows the same table to be put over two different pages (although it's in two separate floats in the doc)